# Parametrized testing in scala with MUnit, is it possible?

Tags: scala, scalatest, scalacheck, parametrized-testing, scala-munit

I am trying to figure out if I can create parametrized tests with MUnit or ScalaCheck.
ScalaCheck allows me to create property-based tests. However, the only way I have seen that I can create parametrized tests is with ScalaTest. See here: https://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/table_driven_property_checks.

My test suite already depends on MUnit and ScalaCheck, I would not like to add another library on the mix. Otherwise, I think I am going to get rid of MUnit and replace it with ScalaTest.

Comment: You are using the wrong tag for munit in Scala. Please read the description. You probably want to use scalameta instead.

Comment: @aled, right. My apologies. Thank you for fixing it.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem that [MUnit](https://scalameta.org/munit) offers something like [Table-driven property checks](https://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/table_driven_property_checks). `MUnit` has [integration with scalacheck](https://scalameta.org/munit/docs/integrations/scalacheck.html), but doesn't add anything similar to what you are looking for.

One possible approach could be something like

```scala
import munit.FunSuite

class MUnitTest extends FunSuite {

  val table = List(
    (1,1),
    (2,-2),
    (3,3)
  )

  for(t <- table) test(s"${t._1} should be equals ${t._2}") {
    assertEquals(t._1, t._2)
  }

}
```

the output will be

```scala
MUnitTest:
  + 1 should be equals 1 0.05s
==> X MUnitTest.2 should be equals -2  0.033s munit.ComparisonFailException: MUnitTest.scala:15
14:  yield test(s"${t._1} should be equals ${t._2}") {
15:    assertEquals(t._1, t._2)
16:  }
values are not the same
=> Obtained
2
=> Diff (- obtained, + expected)
-2
+-2
    at munit.FunSuite.assertEquals(FunSuite.scala:11)
    at MUnitTest.$anonfun$new$2(MUnitTest.scala:15)
  + 3 should be equals 3 0.0s
[error] Failed: Total 3, Failed 1, Errors 0, Passed 2
[error] Failed tests:
[error]     MUnitTest
```

It's not exactly the same. Doing this, instead of having just one use case where the error message of a failed test shows what is the set of values that make the test fails, you will be generating new test cases per each group of values you have in the list. Using the `Table` class also lets put a label for each value, which something useful when you get an error. Even title of the test could be wrong.

This could be improved with some helper, but I think that would be trying to recreate what is offered by `ScalaTest`

Comment: You can add as much metadata as you want, including labels: `val table = List(("label-1", 1, 1), ...)` (which you can then use in test-titles, if you want). Also, I'm pretty sure that the `yield` doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: The code I wrote is very basic. Instead of using tuples you can use case classes to make it more readable. In a few lines it could be ok, but I think in a big project it will be hard to maintain and also you would replicating what is offered by the other library.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin What do you mean with the yield is not doing anything? The output provided was copy pasted from the terminal after I executed `sbt test`

Comment: Yes, but that's because the `test(...) { ... }` has a side-effect of registering the test. There is no result that has to be collected by the `yield`, it's just building a `List((), (), ())` filled with `()`-unit values, which is then discarded.

Comment: Oh, now I get it. You are right. The yield is applying a map over the list. If I'm not wrong without the yield it would be a foreach. Thanks por pointing that out. I will fix it later